# Pull file from Android phone

Tags: android, remote-access

Is it possible to remotly pull files from a Android device with the computer?

Someone got any experience with this act?

Comment: pull files? what kind of files? database or any other?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Explain our questin properly. What do you mean by  "remotly pull files?"

Comment: if you are using eclipse-> open file explorer->click on mnt folder ex. if you want to pull file from sdcard->then select file -> on top there is option pull file to device-> click on that

Answer (score 3):

If you do not wish to automate the task. The easiest way is to use Eclipse DDMS. There you have file-explorer tab, where you can browse files on connected devices and virtual devices.

[image]

Assuming this is what you mean. Not quite sure, since question was bit unclear

Comment: To be more clear, im looking for a file explorer that can be used with a 3G connection.